# Autofill People or Group field with user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, people-picker, newform

I have a list in SP2010 and need the user's name to auto-populate in the "Assigned To" `People or Group field` whenever s/he submits an new item. Thanks!

Comment: Is it an editable field? Are you displaying that field in the New Form?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished by using an InfoPath form. You can create a lookup to the user profile sync (syncs with AD):
[Link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/how-to-set-current-user-name-to-infopath-person-group-picker.aspx)

Alternatively, you might be able to create a workflow that copies the user from "Created By" field into "assigned to."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with default List forms. You can add JavaScript to your form to achieve this as explained in [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/389f66a1-d1c1-4630-b5a5-e8be0b970aa7/how-to-specify-default-value-for-people-or-group-field-in-sharepoint-with-current-user?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) article.

Comment: Thanks! I went to the site and copied the code but it is auto-populating "[object Object]" in the field and not the user name. Any idea what I am doing wrong? THanks!

Comment: I haven't used this myself. But, you can try adding `alert(vals);` in `fillDefaultValues()` function, after the following line in your code.
 _var vals = new Object(getUserDisplayName());_     This is to check if your code is capturing the loggedin user's name properly.